Android expo build
I've a problem with building my react native app on an Android platform via expo.
As you can see in the error message, it seems like the file is missing which is not correct provided by the path. Here's the package.json:

{
  "name": "timetabapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.1.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^5.2.12",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.17",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.6.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.18",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.19.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
    "expo": "~50.0.7",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "i18next": "^23.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1303.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-success-animation": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


Do you know what the problem is?
good to know: building the react native app in an ios plattform was properly fine.
Thanks a lot,
Best Gery

check path
reinstall node modules
reset cache
reinstall npm install -g eas-cli

